# Accessing Add-in Web data from Host Web using same domain

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-addin

In our project we need to download some data from Add-in Web. And it brings some problems.

For example, user have to be logged in on both domains. 
If user is logged in on your website `http://mywebsite.sharepoint.com` and there is a REST call to `http://mywebsite-e72bc262fda58e.sharepoint.com/YourAddInName/_api/web/lists` made by JS, this call will get 302 response with redirect to login page. So user must open `http://mywebsite-e72bc262fda58e.sharepoint.com/YourAddInName/` first, complete the authentication and only after that you can use REST calls to `http://mywebsite-e72bc262fda58e.sharepoint.com/YourAddInName` from Host Web.

To workaround this problem we send REST request to Add-in Web using same domain: `http://mywebsite.sharepoint.com/YourAddInName/_api/web/lists` It works well, but the question we have - how reliable is this way? Is it something officially declared or it may change any moment?

Comment: Good question. Got her looking for information like this, In my case, because I have two developers: UI and "SpDataServices" in a TSVC. They have to work in splitted repositories due to SPO testing landscape, So I have one UI add-in and a Angular $emit scopes dataservice, so UI must consume data from Angular....

Comment: @egidiocs  If you like this question you can vote it up, maybe it will receive more attention then.